# Why do we call it a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

In simple terms, a $\sigma$-algebra is the collection of all of the things we know how to measure. Why don't we call it something that more directly suggests this, for example a 'measure space?'

Comment: We call it measure(able) space. But people tend to think that by giving names to things they know them better. So they call $\sigma$-algebra to part of the information of the measurable space. They call $\sigma$-algebra to the collection of all the measurable sets, and then measurable space to their union together with the collection of its measurable subsets. You are right, it is a waste of words. What can we do? Blame the French, who like to do more literature math Math.

Comment: Note that I am not really sure if it was a French who introduced the terminology, but if you are not sure blame the French anyway.

Comment: In French, we even use the word "Tribu", which makes even less sense

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien *Sacrilège*... Bourbaki invented *tribu*, of course.

Comment: A _measurable space_ is a space (a set) embedded with a _$\sigma$-algebra_. Well, of course there is a bijection between measurable spaces and $\sigma$-algebras, but if that is what it's all about, then you should also complain about the relation between _cardinality_ (of finite sets) and _natural numbers_.. :)

Comment: @Did doesn't make more sense does it? unles they were auto referencing to the Bourbaki trive they are$ even then

Comment: @Jean-Sébastien My first comment was a joke. More seriously, I fail to see in which sense the declaration that calling sigma-algebras *tribu* makes no sense makes sense.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Sure, the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ in a measure space $(X,\mathcal A,m)$ is exactly the collection of subsets $B$ of $X$ such that $m(B)$ exists but to define $\sigma$-algebras as "the collection of all of the things we know how to measure" is to put the cart before the horse since $\sigma$-algebras exist without measure. In fact a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$ on a set $X$ is a subset of $2^X$ with the properties you might know--then one says that $(X,\mathcal A)$ is a measurable space.

Thus, "measure spaces" are triplets $(X,\mathcal A,m)$, whose second bit $\mathcal A$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Note that, in general, tons of measures $m$ can be defined on a same measurable space $(X,\mathcal A)$ hence to call the part $\mathcal A$ by the name of the whole $(X,\mathcal A,m)$ would be absurd.

About terminology now: Greek letters $\sigma$ and $\delta$ (small sigma and small delta) are often used when countable unions and countable intersections are involved. Topologists call $F_\sigma$ every countable union of closed sets in a topological space (F standing possibly for the French word *fermé*, closed) and $G_\delta$ every countable intersection of open sets (G standing for the German word *Gebiet*, domain, connected open set). The letters $\sigma$ and $\delta$ are often given as Greek abbreviations of German words: $\sigma$ as S in *Summe* for sum (in the sense of sum of sets, that is, union) and $\delta$ as D in *Durchschnitt* for intersection, both countable. Thus, in the context of measure theory, the letter $\sigma$ refers to the stability of a collection of subsets by countable union.

Comment: "Forschnitt" is not a German word, "closed" is "abgeschlossen". "Gebiet" means "domain" (connected open set), "neighbourhood" is "Umgebung". I think the "F" actually comes from "fermé", but I could be mistaken there.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the input.

Comment: De rien, vous êtes bienvenu.

Comment: @DanielFischer Das ganze Vergnügen ist für mich.